# Ruby on Rails Create Method `uninitialized constant` error for dropdown value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that is rendering properly and yielding the correct values in my server log, but it's hitting an error when I go to create the actual object.

The model is called `LeadMagnet` and here's the schema:

```
  create_table "lead_magnets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.boolean "motivation", default: false
    t.boolean "mindset", default: false
    t.boolean "resourcing", default: false
    t.boolean "planning", default: false
    t.boolean "time_management", default: false
    t.boolean "discipline", default: false
    t.string "type"
    t.string "link_url"
    t.boolean "active", default: true
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_lead_magnets_on_user_id"
  end
```

The error is being called on my `lead_magnet#create` method on this line:

```
@lead_magnet = LeadMagnet.new(lead_magnet_params)
```

And here are the params it's referring to:

```
def lead_magnet_params
  params.require(:lead_magnet).permit(
    :title,
    :description,
    :motivation,
    :mindset,
    :resourcing,
    :planning,
    :time_management,
    :discipline,
    :type,
    :link_url,
    :active,
    :user_id
  )
end
```

The issue is for the value for "type", which is a string generated by the following code:

```
  <div class="form-group col-12 mb-0 pb-0">
    <%= f.input :type, label: false, prompt: "Select LM Type", input_html: { class: 'mdb-select md-form colorful-select' }, collection: [['Attachment', 'Attachment'], ['Link', 'Link']], required: true %>
  </div>
```

Which in turn creates this in the server log:

```
Started POST "/lead_magnets" for ::1 at 2019-10-05 21:11:07 -0700
Processing by LeadMagnetsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3NYnrPxC6oucYnV25TFOnAmbLjDoRLRisLkbNaisDBV6yCLkg1yXPC6bUo2hzEkrML1VdH+4BY4iLbqgGs0nIg==", "lead_magnet"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>"", "motivation"=>"0", "mindset"=>"0", "resourcing"=>"0", "planning"=>"0", "time_management"=>"0", "discipline"=>"0", "type"=>"Link", "link_url"=>"", "active"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NameError - uninitialized constant Link:
  app/controllers/lead_magnets_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Why is the value "Link" coming across as an uninitialized constant when it should just be a string value?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that "type" is a protected name in Rails.  I changed the column name to `lead_magnet_type` and the error went away.

Comment: Yeah the "type" column is used when setting up Single Table Inheritance for example. It lets you have one table and map the records to different model classes when they are loaded which is pretty cool.